# booting linux toold over PXE in UEFI moce

Tags: linux, networking, pxe

I've been using iPXE to setup a network boot environment in our lab, everything works fine in Legacy mode, but in UEFI I'm unable to boot some linux tools (like clonezilla, parted magic, etc), i tried using the same config from the legacy menu, but i always get an error

`"Kernel panic - not syncing: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"`

I'm sure it's something simple but just can't find any information about this, maybe it's even an issue with iPXE.

Here's my menu for iPXE.

```
:parted
echo Starting PartedMagic 2015 (64bit)
kernel ${http-images}/parted/bzImage64
initrd ${http-images}/parted/initrd.img
initrd ${http-images}/parted/fu.img
initrd ${http-images}/parted/m64.img
initrd ${http-images}/parted/files.cgz
imgargs bzImage64 edd=on vga=normal
boot || goto failed
goto start

:clonezilla
echo Starting CloneZilla with default options
kernel ${http-images}/clonezilla/vmlinuz
initrd ${http-images}/clonezilla/initrd.img
imgargs vmlinuz boot=live toram config noswap nolocales edd=on nomodeset ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" vga=788 nosplash noprompt fetch=${http-images}/clonezilla/filesystem.squashfs union=overlay locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_live_batch="no" ocs_prerun01="mount -t nfs4 143.185.160.4:/storage/images /home/partimag -o noatime,nodiratime"
boot || goto failed
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

iPXE UEFI mode does no have all the features the BIOS mode has.
You do not find UEFI iPXE info because it does not exists. It seems iPXE developer is not really an UEFI enthusiast; I've read him complaining about the whole EFI thing a lot.

Comment: The needed documentation is in the kernel, is specific to Linux kernel EFI stub, as the question about this is common, the documentation is getting better these days.

Answer (score 0):

In EFI mode every initrd that should be used need to be specified in imgargs as well.
This is a limitation of EFI itself, the [Kernel documentation for efi stub](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/efi-stub.txt) has a separate section on the topic